# Developing tools of Java developers

Tags: c#, java, open-source, development-environment, oracle-sqldeveloper

When i developing by `C#` in `Microsoft Windows`, i use `Microsoft Visual Studio` with `Microsoft Team Foundation Server`. I need an ORM so Entity framework can help me, and so on. These tools can be named as Microsoft solutions for Windows Developers.
What is the Sun or Oracle solution for Java developers? Which IDE, Version control, ORM, Web developing tool, database and other programming tools suggested?

Comment: Welcome to the world of open chose...

Comment: Your question matches 2 reasons top close: opinion based and searching for tools... Try to find more suitable place for this question than SO.

Comment: Eclipse IDE with lots of plugins.

Comment: Oracle's IDE for Java development is [JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html). However, [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is widely used, as is [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Comment: I like to have a list of **open source** and **Java** developing tools. @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: 1) are you willing to pay for your ide? 
2) what type of application you will be developing? ie android apps? web aplication? stand alone application?

Comment: You Consider developing client/server application for Android and Linux platforms. @user902383

Comment: @Hossein personally i'm using eclipse, it is good free and has large library of plugins and extensions.  I heard IntelliJ is quite nice, but if you want to do ie commercial jee application, you need to buy it. and thats bring back question are you willing to pay for ide? if not, then get yourself eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IDE, I use IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (there is a paid one with more features including a native bytecode viewer but chances are you won't need that), which has superb code completion, full Git (most popular version control system I know of) integration and a bunch of other features including Groovy, Scala, Android, PHP, Python and more. It has lots of plugins and there's also Eclipse (which has more plugins), Netbeans and more.

For version control you might have seen/heard of Github somewhere since it is by far the most popular one. I use it and there's a drag and drop version of it (Github for Windows) if you're not too comfortable with command-line.

For ORM you could try Hibernate which I've never used before but it looks popular. However more and more people are shifting away from ORMs because they provide a loss of a lot of control with few benefits.

IntelliJ has out of the box support for web development frameworks so if that's something you want check it out.

For databases you should use MySQL and if you're going to be connecting to your own databases on the internet you should get familiar with PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about web developing? @injustice

Comment: As I said, IntelliJ has support for web developing frameworks but also check out Play, Spring, Struts2. Check out this link too http://www.infoq.com/research/jvm-web-frameworks. Also if this helped you, please click the tick next to the the number on the left of my answer :)

Comment: @Injustice doead community version of intellij has support for spring play struts or jee?

Comment: I think so, I haven't tried but it should do.

Answer (score 1):

My current config:
IDE is "Eclipse", Version control with "[SVN](http://subversion.apache.org)", database is "MySQL" together with "[spring](http://www.springsource.org)" framework.